# Can't convert numpy object array to float array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.6

When I load in the saved array from a .npy file, I get an array(**data_train**) which contains two arrays, which looks like the one posted down below.
When I read the docs correct it is a 2d array with two arrays in it, isn t it?

So my problem is, that I do not know how to "extract" the first array(**img**)  out of the one loaded(**data_train**)  in from the .npy file.

Creation of the .npy file:

```
        pressed_k = get_keys.get_pressed_keys()
        img = screen_cap.grab_frame(size)
        tr_data.append([img, pressed_k])
        np.save('data.npy', tr_data)
```

**pressed_k** is an array ([0, 0, 0, 0]) 
**img** is an array too, which contains image data in format: 480,270

To "extract" the **pressed_k** array I am using:

```
batch_y = np.array(np.hstack([i[1] for i in data_train]), dtype=np.float32)
```

Which returns:

```
Shape: (64953,)
Array: [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
```

So far everything is perfectly fine.

But when I try the same for the **img** array:

```
batch_x = np.array([i[0] for i in data_train], dtype=np.float32)
```

it returns:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

When I try the same with *dtype=object*:

```
batch_x = np.array([i[0] for i in data_train], dtype=object)
```

It works but in the function in which **batch_x** is used later on, it throws the same error again.

GitHub page: https://github.com/MrGrimod/gta_self_driving

**data_train**:

```
  [[0 0]
  [0 0]
[0 0]
...,
[ array([[[212, 194, 179, 255],
      [212, 194, 179, 255],
      [212, 195, 179, 255],
      ...,
      [ 68,  69,  70, 255],
      [ 61,  65,  61, 255],
      [152, 134,  11, 255]],

     [[211, 194, 180, 255],
      [212, 194, 180, 255],
      [212, 195, 179, 255],
      ...,
      [ 66,  68,  63, 255],
      [ 63,  67,  59, 255],
      [153, 134,   9, 255]],

     [[210, 193, 181, 255],
      [211, 194, 181, 255],
      [212, 195, 180, 255],
      ...,
      [ 69,  71,  72, 255],
      [ 71,  72,  73, 255],
      [153, 134,   9, 255]],

     ...,
     [[ 40,  40,  47, 255],
      [ 45,  46,  51, 255],
      [ 37,  37,  43, 255],
      ...,
      [ 45,  47,  54, 255],
      [ 47,  49,  56, 255],
      [146, 130,   9, 255]],

     [[ 40,  40,  47, 255],
      [ 42,  42,  48, 255],
      [ 32,  32,  38, 255],
      ...,
      [ 40,  41,  48, 255],
      [ 42,  43,  48, 255],
      [147, 131,  10, 255]],

     [[ 39,  40,  46, 255],
      [ 35,  35,  41, 255],
      [ 32,  33,  38, 255],
      ...,
      [ 43,  44,  51, 255],
      [ 41,  42,  49, 255],
      [147, 131,  11, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
 array([0, 0, 0, 0])]
 [ array([[[212, 194, 179, 255],
      [212, 194, 179, 255],
      [212, 195, 179, 255],
      ...,
      [ 70,  71,  73, 255],
      [ 67,  68,  66, 255],
      [152, 134,  11, 255]],

     [[211, 193, 180, 255],
      [212, 194, 180, 255],
      [212, 195, 180, 255],
      ...,
      [ 68,  69,  70, 255],
      [ 68,  70,  69, 255],
      [153, 134,   9, 255]],

     [[209, 193, 182, 255],
      [211, 194, 181, 255],
      [212, 195, 180, 255],
      ...,
      [ 69,  72,  74, 255],
      [ 71,  72,  73, 255],
      [153, 134,   9, 255]],

     ...,
     [[ 41,  41,  49, 255],
      [ 46,  46,  52, 255],
      [ 37,  37,  43, 255],
      ...,
      [ 46,  47,  54, 255],
      [ 47,  49,  57, 255],
      [146, 130,   9, 255]],

     [[ 41,  41,  48, 255],
      [ 42,  42,  48, 255],
      [ 32,  32,  38, 255],
      ...,
      [ 41,  42,  48, 255],
      [ 41,  43,  49, 255],
      [147, 131,  10, 255]],

     [[ 40,  40,  46, 255],
      [ 32,  33,  38, 255],
      [ 32,  33,  38, 255],
      ...,
      [ 43,  44,  51, 255],
      [ 41,  42,  49, 255],
      [147, 131,  11, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
        array([0, 0, 0, 0])]
       [ array([[[211, 195, 180, 255],
      [212, 195, 180, 255],
      [212, 195, 180, 255],
      ...,
      [ 68,  69,  69, 255],
      [ 62,  64,  72, 255],
      [152, 134,  11, 255]],

     [[210, 193, 181, 255],
      [211, 194, 181, 255],
      [212, 195, 180, 255],
      ...,
      [ 63,  65,  57, 255],
      [ 49,  55,  61, 255],
      [153, 134,   9, 255]],

     [[211, 193, 181, 255],
      [212, 195, 181, 255],
      [212, 195, 181, 255],
      ...,
      [ 56,  59,  47, 255],
      [ 45,  50,  58, 255],
      [153, 134,   9, 255]],

     ...,
     [[ 42,  43,  50, 255],
      [ 47,  48,  55, 255],
      [ 37,  38,  44, 255],
      ...,
      [ 42,  44,  49, 255],
      [ 46,  48,  54, 255],
      [146, 130,   9, 255]],

     [[ 42,  44,  50, 255],
      [ 40,  41,  47, 255],
      [ 34,  35,  41, 255],
      ...,
      [ 37,  38,  44, 255],
      [ 37,  38,  43, 255],
      [147, 131,  10, 255]],

     [[ 40,  42,  48, 255],
      [ 34,  35,  41, 255],
      [ 34,  35,  41, 255],
      ...,
      [ 45,  48,  55, 255],
      [ 42,  43,  50, 255],
      [147, 131,  11, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
array([0, 0, 0, 0])]]
shape: (16614, 2)
created by appending two array, saving it and then loading it, by using 
np.load
```

Comment: *"when I load in the saved array from a .npy file..."*  Show the code where you do this.

Comment: Ok, I added explanation.

Comment: Pls help me....

Comment: It is much easy to get help if you show [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you add it?

Comment: Ok, is it better like that?

Comment: @MrPete: What we want/need is basically 1-20 lines of code which get us from a fresh interpreter to the error you are having.

Comment: Aha, ok. But I don t know how to reproduce the problem without executing the whole code.

Comment: I would do anything to help you... But I don t know how to. Sry.